# can you return from a method early in an objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing some networking stuff in one of my methods and I would like the method to `return NO` and stop executing early if one of the internal calls returns an error, a bit like break for loops. Is this possible?

IMO it would produce cleaner code rather than using a BOOL flag and having "should I continue executing this code?" if statements all over the place; and then finally at the end of the method returning YES or NO based on the flag.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
return NO;
```

Return statements are acceptable everywhere in functions and methods. I personally prefer to make use of early returns because it usually leads to less nesting (and thus code easier to understand).

There are several similar questions around here:

- [Should I use early returns in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071764/should-i-use-early-returns-in-c)
- [Is it bad to have multiple return statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939162/is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-return-statements)
- [Should a function have only one return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)

Comment: Agreed on the early return.  One caveat;  if you are using retain-release (not Garbage Collection), be careful to release any retained variables prior to the early return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's exactly what I did in my code but the method still execute to the end... or so I thought because I saw a log message in the terminal that I thought was being printed from within the method. It turned out I was printing the message not from within the method but back from where I was calling the method. Silly mistake.

I looked at the other threads but because of my coding error assumed it would be different in ObjC.

Thanks again!